# Replace multiple new lines only

Tags: php, regex, replace, newline

I am trying to do something kind of unusual. I want to replace multiple new lines with two new lines. There are plenty of questions like that but not exactly, see:

`Hello\n\n\nWorld\n\n\n\n!`

Should become

`Hello\n\nWorld\n\n!`

This however

`Hello\nWorld\n!`

Should stay the same. The problem with my regex is that it replaces single new lines with two.

`preg_replace('"(\r?\n)+"', "\n\n", $somevar)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

something like this?

```
preg_replace('"(\r?\n){2,}"', "\n\n", $somevar)
```

Comment: A cross platform solution: `preg_replace('#(\r\n?|\n){2,}#', '$1$1', $string);`.