# How to replace repeated new lines with one removing single new lines?

Tags: python, regex

I am new to python. I am trying to clean texts
Looking for a function that will do

1. `regex_replace('\n{2,}', '\n\n', text);`
2. `regex_replace('\n', '', text);`

```
sample = "he\nll\no\n\n\n\n My nam\ne is je\nff\n\nNew to Python";
```

```
#expected_output = "hello\n\nMy name is jeff\n\nNew to Python'
```

[php similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16793243/replace-multiple-new-lines-only)

Comment: You are looking for `re.sub`. refer: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub

Comment: @anotherGatsby is there a better way than doing 3 `re.sub` in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with alternation and a capture group:

```py
(\n\n)\n*|\n
```

Replacement would be `\1` to make sure we get `\n\n` for the case when there are more than 2 line breaks and an empty string when there is just `\n`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CojdRT/1)

**Code:**

```py
import re

s = "he\nll\no\n\n\n\n My nam\ne is je\nff\n\nNew to Python"
print ( re.sub('(\n\n)\n*|\n', r'\1', s) )
```

**Output:**

```py
hello

 My name is jeff

New to Python
```